# Android Hashmap File I/O

Tags: android, dictionary

I am writing an Android application that fills up a Map on launch, and then when done, saves it to file. However, since this file can take up to 10 seconds to retrieve, I would like to know how to check if the file exists before getting it again, and if it does exist, just load it up into the Map object.

```
private Map<String, String> idMap;
```

If there is an even better way of saving this Map, let me know please.

(This is meant to be used as a form of dictionary)

```
Key: Corona
Value: 172

Key: Beer
Value: 199
```

Let me know if there is any more information you would need.

Comment: I don't know what exactly your are trying to achieve but based on the information you have provided it would probably be a better idea to use a SQLite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `File.exists()` method to check if the file already exists:

```
File mapFile = new File(PATH_TO_MAP_FILE);
if (mapFile.exists() && mapFile.isFile()) {
    // Load from file
} else {
    // Create the map the slow way
}
```

As for alternatives, if you're just storing key-value pairs, you might want to consider using `SharedPreferences` to store the values instead of implementing your own solution. It will persist keys and values (of multiple types) to an XML file. It is also thread-safe and fast for reading.

Comment: mapFile.exists() will return Tru for a directory too, you should check with .isFile() :)

Comment: Will I be able to do that through a request? To elaborate, this is a web service that replies with a fairly large array of keys/values in XML form already.